# How to receive webhook by C

Tags: c

I want to receive webhook (HTTP POST) of kazoo by my C program. 
I think it rise my knowledge and its so funny (I think what earlier).

I try to catch HTTP POST request but cant heard anything. What I do and understanding wrong ?

I can target to webhook which binary/script it may execute then event generate.

For example ("http://server/c/hookreceiver.bin") and full example

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"data":{"name": "hookreceiver.bin", "uri": "http://server/c/hookreceiver.bin","http_verb": "post","hook": "channel_create","retries":4}}'
```

apache log:

```
"POST /c/hookreceiver.bin HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "-"
```

I can catch this POST by php if I setuped to webhook my script (webhookExample.php)

But if I try to catch this POST by C I have not anything :(

Why I cant receive anything by c and can if I use php ?

Sorry for strange questions
And thanks for your time

P.S.
How I can debug my program by gdb or something else in this mode then my binary call some another applications ?

webhookExample.php

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$my_file = 'MYfile.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
?>

file hookreceiver.bin
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int portno =        80;
char *host =        "SERVER_NAME";

struct hostent *server;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
int sockfd, bytes, received, total;
char response[4096];

FILE *fp;
char name1[] = "./MY_FLAG.txt";
char name[100];
sprintf(name, "%s_%d",name1,  getpid() );
if ((fp = fopen(name, "w")) == NULL) {
    // Error open
    return 0;
}

// create the socket 
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) fprintf(fp, "ERROR opening socket");
else            fprintf(fp, "sock ok\n");

// lookup the ip address 
server = gethostbyname(host);
if (server == NULL) fprintf(fp, "ERROR, no such host");

// fill in the structure 
memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

// connect the socket 
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    fprintf(fp, "ERROR connecting");
else
    fprintf(fp, "ok - conn |%d|\n", sockfd );
fflush(fp);

bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,4096,NULL, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if (bytes < 0)
    fprintf(fp, "ERROR reading response from socket\n");
else
    fprintf(fp, "ok - bytes > 0 %d |%s|\n",bytes, response);
// close the socket 
close(sockfd);
fprintf(fp, "ok - END\n");
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Result for php script

```
cat MYfile.txt
```

account_id=24..7&owner_id=3e03&request=udev2Cnsl%40server.local&reseller_id=2c7&timestamp=63720841342&...

Result for C program

```
cat MY_FLAG.txt_27968 
sock ok
ok - conn |4|
ok - prepare for receive
ok - bytes > 0 0 ||
ok - received == total
ok - END
```

Comment: Now I can found that php://input read data of HTTP POST request. SeI can understand Consequently I can read this but I cant understand which is address I would setup for read this data. May be anybody know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is absurdly cheapest.

**Server is simple write text to the stdin.**

For processing webhook server do HTTP POST request "POST /c/hookreceiver.bin HTTP/1.1"

and call binary hookreceiver.bin

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *fp;    
    char name1[] = "./CATCHED_HOOK.txt";    
    char buf[1];    

    sprintf(name, "%s_%d",name1,  getpid() );    

    if ((fp = fopen(name, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("File not opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while(read(0,buf, sizeof(mbuf))>0) {
        fprintf(fp,buf);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

cat CATCHED_HOOK.txt_1212232

account_id=2424c7&authorizing_id=0b3316d6&authorizing_type=device&call_direction=inbound&call_id=1169696&caller_id_name=udev1Cnsl&caller_id_number=udev1Cnsl&&&emergency_resource_used=false&from=udev1Cnsl40ce.local&local_resource_used=true&is_internal_leg=false&owner_id=866ae5&request=300240ce.local&reseller_id=244e36be95324c7&timestamp=63722050107&to=300240ce.local&hook_event=channel_createok - END